# How to make a bot identify you either by ID or permission

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm having a problem where my bot only identifies by permission, I even made sure that my ID was where the `!message.author.id ==` was. I removed the `!` from `!message.author.id` and it my bot still relies on the permission

I tried
 - Removing the ! from the `!message.author.id`
 - Adding a `else` after the return message
 - Finding similar issues
 - And searched the Discord.JS documentation.

```
if(!message.author.id ==`329023088517971969` || !message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_GUILD'])) return message.channel.send(`You don't have the permissions to do this!`)
<code here>
```

I expect the output to be that IF the bot finds my ID (the author) is the same as the value after, it would let me pass, OR if both statements are true it would let me pass, OR if the hasPermission was true, it would let me pass.
The actual result is that it only relies on the hasPermission and ignores the author ID.

Basically
Bot should: Either run code after the `if()` if the author's id is equal to the one shown in the code, or member has the following permissions

Comment: `if(message.author.id ==="329023088517971969" || message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_GUILD']))` isn't working for you ?

Comment: Weirdly, what's working is `if(!message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_GUILD']) || message.author.id ==="329023088517971969") return message.channel.send(`You don't have the permissions to do this!`)` For the MANAGE_GUILD side, and `if(message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_GUILD']) || message.author.id !="329023088517971969") return message.channel.send(`You don't have the permissions to do this!`)` only the author ID works, combining them just doesn't work out. I'm wondering if one or the other takes priority of the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using all negated conditions, you should use the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) operator (`&&`), not the [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) operator (`||`).

```js
if (message.author.id !== '329023088517971969' && !message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD')) {
  return message.channel.send(':x: Insufficient permission.')
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

In English, this code basically says "if this isn't the author's ID **and** they don't have the permission flag, stop." Logically, it makes more sense than "if this isn't the author's ID **or** they don't have the permission flag" because if one is true and the other is false, it would stop you.

Consider this example:

```js
const str = 'abcd';
const arr = ['foo'];

if (str !== 'abcd' || !arr.includes('bar')) console.log('This is WRONG.');
//      false      OR        true             OUTPUTS                true

if (str !== 'abcd' && !arr.includes('bar')) console.log('This is correct (you won\'t see this).');
//      false      AND       true             OUTPUTS                false
```

Answer (score 0):

try put the conditions in separate function return true/false and check what its output will be. it could be easier to check which part of condition is not working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your condition to this

```
if(message.author.id !='329023088517971969' || !message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_GUILD'])) return message.channel.send(`You don't have the permissions to do this!`)
```

notice you have `!message.author.id =='329023088517971969'` which is not correct so you need to change that with `message.author.id !='329023088517971969;'`

Comment: i don't have a manage guild permission on a guild, so it has to rely on my ID. this code always returns for me

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question, but sounds like the following pice of code is enough. I suggest avoiding the usage of negating conditions because is hard to read.

```
boolean authorHasNotPermission = message.author.id !== '329023088517971969';
boolean memberHasNotPermission = !message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_GUILD']);

if (authorHasNotPermission || memberHasNotPermission) {
   return message.channel.send(`You don't have the permissions to do this!`)
}
```